# Converting all float in string by whole number PhP

Tags: php, svg, str-replace

**CONTEXT**

I have a svg file shaped like following :

```
<svg width="100px" height="150px">
    <g>
        <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="2125.9858">
        </linearGradient>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Note this is an example, in reality my svg is bigger.

**GOAL**

I would like to input this as a string in php, and find all float, then finally convert those to whole number. The aim of this script is to round all number to reduce the load for rendering in client screen.

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
<svg width="100px" height="150px">
    <g>
        <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="2125">
        </linearGradient>
    </g>
</svg>
```

**QUESTION**

Can I use `str_replace` to do the job ? I thought of something that would be near this command :

```
$svg = "...";
$svg = str_replace("/[0-9.]/", floor(the_occurence_found), $svg);
```

Is that possible ? Or am I going right on the wall ?

Comment: No, str_replace() doesn't recognise regular expressions; but using [preg_replace_callback()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) would be viable

Comment: Does what you're trying to do actually reduce the client-side load?  Because I doubt it does, at least in any way you'd be able to benchmark.

Comment: it's svg, which means it's xml. don't use regexes. use a DOM parser.

Comment: Why would rounding reduce the client load?

Comment: I think it will since I use a javascript plugin that handle drag'n'drop, zoom, and those kind of event need the svg to re-compute for rendering so I guess process whole numbers is less cpu-costing than float (the file is 13Kb). the function mentionned by @MarkBaker seems to work but I need a deeper workaround to prevent rounding value like opacity.

Comment: Absolute nosense, any conforming viewer will store values as floating point no matter what. All you'll save is an unmeasurably tiny amount of network bandwidth.

Comment: Just finished to round my file, in fact this was not a matter of precision on path points that slow the rendering, but the number of path the browser have to render. Going from 13kb to 7kb has slightly improved the rendering performance on Chrome but remains laggy on IE / FF. Just wanted to clear this up for the one who wondered since I did not found any benchmark on the internet dealing with this question of svg performance.